# Finding matching pairs of identifiers in a data frame

Tags: r

I have a dataframe `df`:

```
id1 id2 action
  1   2     10
  1   3     11
  1   4     21
  2   1      6
...
```

It means, the user `id1` do something (`10`) to user `id2`, and `id2` do something (`6`) to `id1`.

Now I want to create a new column, called `partner_action`, which basically records what did the partner do. So it will look like:

```
id1 id2 action partner_action
  1   2     10              6
  2   1      6             10
  1   3     11              9
  3   1      9             11
```

I tried:

```
df$partner_action = df[df$id2 == df$id1,]$action
```

But of course, it does not work.

I thought about make a copy of `df`, called `df_copy` then:

```
df$partner_action = df_copy[df_copy$id1 == df$id2,]$action
```

But is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want to merge `df` with itself, matching pairs of `(id2, id1)` with pairs of `(id1, id2)`. You can do this in R either with `merge` or `match`:

```
df$partner_action <- with(df, action[match(paste(id2, id1), paste(id1, id2))])
df
#   id1 id2 action partner_action
# 1   1   2     10              6
# 2   2   1      6             10
# 3   1   3     11              9
# 4   3   1      9             11
```

Data:

```
(df <- data.frame(id1=c(1, 2, 1, 3), id2=c(2, 1, 3, 1), action=c(10, 6, 11, 9)))
#   id1 id2 action
# 1   1   2     10
# 2   2   1      6
# 3   1   3     11
# 4   3   1      9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df))
{df[i,4]<-df[which(df$id1==df[i,2]&df$id2==df[i,1]),3]}
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation and mixing in some spaces for better readability might help